# Difference between imputing and typing in GWAS studies?

Tags: bioinformatics, gwas

In genome-wide association studies (GWAS), what is the difference between imputing and typing? Are they the same?

Answer (score 2):

'Typing' is an SNV-typing. It is an explicit SNV detection using Affymetrix [GeneChip](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18803882/) arrays, Illumina [BeadArray](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15829238/).

'Imputing' is an imputation. It is a statistical inferring from existing genotype data using haplotype estimation. It is useful because different genotyping arrays genotype a slightly different set of SNVs and they can't detect all variants as whole genome sequencing is still pricey.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different altogether.

Typing in GWAS is genotyping individuals from a selected population to know say the genetic variation of SNP's (single nucleotide polymorphisms) among them via chips like [Illumina Core-Exome etc.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2925172/)

Imputing is the statistical process of imputation of SNP's of an individual from a reference source like the HapMap reference panel. The process is a bit complex and typical tools like IMPUTE2/BEAGLE4/MINIMAC2 rely on HMM (Hidden Markov Models) to fill in the SNP's.

So, in essence within a GWAS study first, we genotype individuals (as it's cheaper than sequencing all SNP's) and get 300-500k SNP's via the chips as above, then impute the remaining variants using an established Human Genome Reference panel using the above software.

Edit:

An excellent resource for understanding imputation is [Yun Li's 2009 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2925172/).

Comment: Please add some references to your response.

Comment: I have added one here, but I usually don't see references in the answers from most of the people in this forum !!!